# Publisher name does not appear on the UAC dialog

Tags: certificate, uac

I've signed my .msi with this command line:

signtool.exe sign /f mycert.pfx /p  /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /d "MSIName.msi" /v "MSIName.msi".

The 'Digital Signature' tab is displayed on the .msi properties dialog and contains the right information but when the UAC dialog appears the 'Publish Name' is still 'Unknown'. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

is your certificate in the trusted publisher certificate store?